# Any quick way to get a Movieclip to scroll in Flash?

Tags: flash, user-interface, scroll, actionscript-2

I need a way to get a (**content**) MovieClip within a (**container**) MovieClip to be scrollable using a scrollbar.

Flash AS2 Components

- **ScrollArea** - Can only scroll externally loaded SWFs.
- **UIScrollBar** - Can only scroll TextFields.

How to scroll an internal MovieClip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AS2 should also have the ScrollPane component (atleast I do). 
The trick is that you can set a **linkage identifier** as the contentPath. The linkage identifier is set by creating a MovieClip, right clicking it in the library, selecting properties, clicking the "export for actionscript" checkbox and then entering it in the corresponding textfield.

This is also what you need to do if you want to put things in a ScrollPane at runtime, then you set the contentPath to an empty MovieClip in your library and just attach your clips into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pure flash, check out ScrollPane, which is included in Flash CS3. If you're using Flex, most container objects have scrolling capabilities.